# When reload de App's page my params missing

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a issue with a bug. When I'm refresh the page of the mobile app, part of the params miss. 
When the parameters are passed incorrectly, the "rerdirect" results in "/" instead of returning the corresponding object.

I'm work with Angular 8 and Typescript. I tryed resolve it creating the params again, but that not work.

This is the function that receives the parameters, when reloading "params" is incomplete.
Then redirect becomes "/".

```
    searchForm(toolKey, params): EventEmitter<any> {
    this.toolKey = toolKey;
    this.getSearchFormCobus(params).first().subscribe(
      (response) => {
        if (response['redirect']) {
          this.event.emit(response['redirect']);
          return;
        }
        this.searchFormData = this.searchFormService.initSearchFormData(this.searchFormData);
        this.initSearchFormData();
        this.searchFormData = this.searchFormService.resolveConfig(this.searchFormData, response);
        this.searchFormData.relations = response.relations;
        this.searchFormData.passengers = response.passengersInfo;
        this.searchFormData.numTraveling = response.config.numberOfPassengers;
        this.searchFormData.authorization = response.authorizationInfo;
        this.searchFormData.transportingAirlines =
          [response.authorizationInfo.transportingAirlineDefault];
        this.event.emit(this.searchFormData);
      },
      (error) => {
        this.event.emit(Observable.throw(error));
      }
    );

    return this.event;
  }

  initSearchFormData() {}

  getSearchFormCobus(params): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post(
      `${this.config.get('apiUrl')}/api/v1/flights/cobus_form_config.json`,
      params,
      { headers: this.headerHelper.getHeadersJson() }
    );
  }
```

The function is called from here.

```
this.searchFormService.searchForm(this.toolKey, this.params.data).first().subscribe((response) => {
      if (response.hasOwnProperty('error') && response.error !== '') {
        this.initHasError = true;
        this.loading.hide('searchForm');
        return;
      }
      if (response['redirect']) {
        return RedirectHelper.root(this.navCtrl, response['redirect']);
      }
      this.searchFormConfigData = response;
      this.searchButtonDisabled = false;

      if (this.toolKey === 'ticketing') {
        this.flightProgramService.getApplicablePrograms(this.searchFormConfigData.passengers.remainingProgramsDetails)
          .subscribe((flightPrograms) => {
            this.flightPrograms = flightPrograms;
            this.loading.hide('flightPrograms');
            if (this.flightPrograms.length > 0) {
              this.shouldDisplayFlightPrograms = true;
            }
          }
        );
      } else {
        this.loading.hide('flightPrograms');
      }

      if (this.searchFormConfigData.allowedToBook === false) {
        this.searchButtonDisabled = true;
      }

      if (!this.welcomeMessage && this.searchFormConfigData.welcomeMessage !== '') {
        this.storage.set('welcomeMessage', this.searchFormConfigData.welcomeMessage);
        this.welcomeMessage = this.searchFormConfigData.welcomeMessage;
      } else {
        this.storage.get('welcomeMessage').first().subscribe((value) => {
          this.welcomeMessage = value;
        });
```

The parameters are loaded here in Nav Params.

```
import { IonicPage, AlertController, NavController, ModalController, NavParams, Events } from 'ionic-angular';

constructor(private navCtrl: NavController,
              private alertCtrl: AlertController,
              public loading: LoadingHelper,
              private translate: TranslateService,
              private events: Events,
              private fb: FormBuilder,
              private modalCtrl: ModalController,
              private searchFormFactory: SearchFormFactory,
              public params: NavParams,
              public storage: StorageService,
              private ga: GoogleAnalytics,
              private fbHelpers: FacebookEventsHelpers,
              private flightProgramService: FlightProgramService) {
  }
```

How can I avoid losing the parameters when reloading the application page?